# Adding multiple CC in Outlook Mail

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have this line of code I've tried to add multiple CC's in the Outlook Mail. But it only returns `;`. I have found this sample at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508919.aspx).

```
Dim ccMail as String
Dim ccRow as Long
Dim objMail as Object
ccRow = Cells(Rows.count, 16).End(xlUp).Row

With objMail
        .Subject = Sheet1.TextBox1.Value
        For k = 4 To ccRow
            ccMail = ccMail & ";" & Cells(k, 1).Value
        Next k
        .cc = ccMail
end with
```

All of the CC Recipients is found in column P.
Any help?Thanks.

Comment: See example here [Email a single attachment from folder of files each to a different person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255106/email-a-single-attachment-from-folder-of-files-each-to-a-different-person)

Answer (score 1):

You used `With objMail` but did not specify Worksheet for `Cells(k, 1).Value`. This is likely to result in an error.

In addition, I presume you want to refer to `ws.Cells(k, 16)` instead since what you want is column P.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Example on how to loop using [*Do-Until Loops*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_do_until_loop.htm) to get cell Values.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim olRecip As Object
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim Recip As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    iRow = 2

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Sht
        With olMail
             Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 16))
                 Recip = Cells(iRow, 16).Value
                 Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
                     olRecip.Type olCC
                     olRecip.Resolve
                 iRow = iRow + 1
             Loop

            .Subject = "Subject"
            .Body = "Hi " & .Body
            .Display
        End With
    End With

    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

*[Do-Until loop and IsEmpty](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299036)*