# Pass cell value to .To and .CC

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I send a range of cells from a workbook to Outlook.

I've tweaked just a little bit the following macro from Ron de Bruin http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm.

It's like this now (just the part that I've edited):

```
With Sendrng

    .Parent.Select
    Set rng = ActiveCell
    .Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        With .Item
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = "XXX"
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display
            .Save
            .Close olPromtForSave
        End With

    End With
```

I want to set .To = "K1" and .CC = "M1:M4". These are cells from the same active workbook. Tweaking a little bit with the cell.Value and for For Each cell In Columns("K") from this link didn't work http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail5.htm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.To = Range("K1")
For each cel in Range("M1:M4")
    Dim sCC as String
    sCC = sCC & ";" & cel.Value2
Next
.CC = Mid(sCC,2) 'to cut off initial ";"
```

Comment: Sorry, pressed entedr before finishing the last comment. Anyway, Out look didn't read that, the e-mail wasn't even created this time and I have the Outlook Object Library active.

Comment: You won't get a better answer I fear... Check what's inside sCC and where the error occurs

Comment: @AndersonPimentel -  Also you can't use `MailEnvelope` with Outlook. If you send the mail through the Outlook object the syntax is different. Look at Ron de Bruin's stuff more carefully to see the difference in syntax.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel see if this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709