# Struggling to attach files to Outlook e-mails using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying something fairly simple, and I can't tell how what I'm doing is different from how other code that's written is doing it.

I have a very simple send e-mails from Excel using Outlook:

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    With OutMail
        .To = Range("ETF_CAB_Recon_Initial_Email_To")
        .CC = Range("ETF_CAB_Recon_Initial_Email_CC")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("ETF_CAB_Recon_Initial_Email_Subject")
        .HTMLBody = Range("ETF_CAB_Recon_Initial_Email_Body")
        .Attachments.Add Range("ETF_CAB_Recon_Initial_Email_Attachment")
        .Display  
    End With


    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, it gets grumpy at my file attachment.

Error message: `"Object doesn't support this property or method"` Doing some research, that's apparently because .add isn't a part of Attachments? But then why do so many examples have Attachments.Add as their code for attaching files to Outlook e-mails?

I've made sure that the Outlook object library is on, and the rest of the email fills in nicely - just not the attachment. Debugging is also showing the attachment as the issue.

I've tried a few different ways of defining the location.

Any guidance towards a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: NAA, but the first thing I would suggest is to use strongly-typed variables -- `Dim outApp As New Outlook.Application`, instead of `Dim outApp As Object: Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. The reference to the Outlook object library in and of itself doesn't really do anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709

Comment: I've been burned before trying to work with outlook without the object library up, so I thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: When you write `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`, you're asking Windows to give you an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object. But VBA has no knowledge that the object under question is an `Outlook.Application` object; as far as VBA is concerned, you could write the following `outApp.NotAMethod()` and VBA would happily compile it and try to run it. Adding the reference to Outlook tells VBA the shape of an `Outlook.Application` object, but you still have to specify that this particular variable refers to an `Outlook.Application` object. Once you've done that, the VBA environment ...

Comment: ... can tell you that `outApp` isn't supposed to have `NotAMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try to fully qualify your workbook  and assign string variable to your range*

*See example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Sht As Object
    Dim RecipTo As String
    Dim RecipCC As String
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Atmt As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Sht
        RecipTo = Sht.Range("A1").Value
        RecipCC = Sht.Range("B1").Value
        Subject = Sht.Range("C1").Value
        Atmt = Sht.Range("D1").Value ' Attachment Path

        With OutMail
            .To = RecipTo
            .CC = RecipCC
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Subject
            .HTMLBody = Sht.Range("E1")
            .Attachments.Add Atmt
            .Display
        End With

    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

*See another example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709*

*[Attachments Object (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864730.aspx)*

Answer (score 2):

Attachments.Add only takes either a string (file name) or an instance of one of Outlook items (such as MailItem). You are passing a Range object.

Comment: How can I convert the range object (which is currently set to a single cell, with just a filepath in it) into a string? One of my attempts was 

Dim AttachmentFilePath as Long

....

And I realized typing this out why that didn't work for me - going to try it dimmed as String

Comment: Range.Value property