# Sending customised email to multiple recipients via macro

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to send an email that is customized to the recipient to over hundred recipients.

I am able to send out my email to one person now but I have no idea how to loop it for multiple recipients and to change the content inside.

I have something like this and it works but I have no idea how to proceed

```
With OutlookMailItem
.To = Range("O2").Value
.Subject = "Promotion campaign"
.Body = "Dear Sir/Madam," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "You are eligible for & Range("A2").Value & _
       "Please follow the instruction below to redeem your gift"
```

Comment: Don't send such spams to anyone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice place to looking for a solution in this kind of issues is:
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail8.htm

Below you'll find code which is what you want to achieve, i think.

**Assumptions:**

- List of e-mails addresses starts from A1
- List of, for example names, starts from B1. If you want to make some more changes just modify `.Body`
- List of subjects starts from C1

For now i use `.Display` method which just showing all emails, but if you change it to `.Send` it will automatically send these mails without showing them

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_Attachment_1()
'Working in 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim intHowManyRows As Integer
```

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

intHowManyRows = Application.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For r = 1 To intHowManyRows
    'Save, Mail, Close and Delete the file
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Cells(r, 1).Value
        .Subject = Cells(r, 3).Value
        '.Attachments.Add FullName  -> If you want to add attachments
        .Body = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "How are you " & Cells(r, 2)
        .Display  'Or use Send
    End With

Next r


Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: OMG it works like wonder, thank you so much! Can I ask what does "intHowManyRows = Application.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count" do? Does it mean it will finds the last row that has a value?

Comment: Yes :) It's the same like set cursor at A1 and hit once CTRL + A - the whole table is selected - and after that i'm counting how many rows we have in that table. That's why when you paste there more items, it will dynamically count how many mail should be sent :) ps. you're welcome ;) If this post was useful for you please vote up. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to add your signature in emails, place it in .Body. For Example: .Body = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "How are you " & Cells(r, 2) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Best regards," & vbNewLine & "SuShuang"

Comment: Sorry, one last question, for now, all the email windows just pop up after I run the macro, is there a way to make it such that after I click send or cancel then the macro proceed to pop up the next email to be sent  out? Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: So you want program to ask you each time if you are sure you want to send this mail? Or maybe you want just send all items without asking (or just one question)?

Comment: I want the program to just ask me once but pops up the email window one at a time, instead of displaying 20 email windows at a time as it lags the whole computer. Is it possible? Thank you so much!