# How to reference a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to send a picture from an Excel file, to a list of email addresses in the same file.

How do I reference the range?

```vb
Sub Email_picture()
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set mi = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    mi.Display
    mi.To = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3")
    mi.Subject = "Picture"
    
    Set doc = mi.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    doc.Range(0, 0).InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\msr\Documents\Slide2.jpg"
    
End Sub
```

It is the line `mi.To = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3")`.

Comment: see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range` is an Excel specific COM object. Outlook would not know what to do with it. You need to loop through all cells explicitly and use their values to either construct a ";" separated list of addresses that you can assign to the `To` property, or you can use the value of each cell to call `Recipients.Add` to add one address at a time.