# How do I loop through a range of 10 e-mail addresses and add them to email in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a simple VBA script that attaches a range of my excel sheet as an attachment to an email.

Now I need to loop through a range of `mail-adresses` (let's say this is column A) and add them as recipients.

I have to the following code that automates the attachment but I don't know how to implement adding the mail-addresses to the email.

How do I implement this in below code?

```
Sub Mail_Range()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Range("A1:K50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Selection of " & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "test@test.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

-- EDIT

I used `=TEXT.COMBINE(";";TRUE; AJ4:AJ15)` to combine the mailadresses into one string (in cell AJ16).

Next I added the range to `OutMail.to = Range("AJ16")` but executing the macro doesn't show the recipients in the mail. How do I solve this?

```
With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = Range("AJ16")
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Feel free to remove it from any code you find with this structure for sending mail.  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the range values as text delimited by `;` and set it as `To` value in your code.

---

```
'/Takes a vertical range and returns values as delimited text
Function GetAddressList(rng As Range)

    Dim arrEmails
    
    arrEmails = rng
    arrEmails = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arrEmails, , 1))
    GetAddressList = Join(arrEmails, ",")
    
End Function

'/ This is how you use GetAddressList
Sub test()
    MsgBox GetAddressList(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10"))
End Sub
```

---

so something like this `OutMail.To =  GetAddressList(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10"))`

---

if you have newer Excel version then you can simply use `TextJoin` in one of the cells and then call that value directly

`=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1:A10)`

Comment: Hi, I used =TEXTJOIN and it combines mailadresses as expected. Now I try to add the outcomes of this formula (that are in cell AJ16) to the email but somehow it does not work and leaves the Outmail. Will extend above

Answer (score 0):

*Another example would be*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    Dim Emails_Address_Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Emails_Address_Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Emails_Address")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Emails As String
    For Each Cell In Emails_Address_Sht.Range("A1", _
                     Emails_Address_Sht.Range("A100").End(xlUp))
        Emails = Emails & Cell & ";"
    Next
    
    With Email
        .To = Emails
        .Subject = "Hello"
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways for adding recipients to the email:

- Modifying the `To`, `Cc`, `Bcc` properties that are represented by a string.
- The [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 

    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 

    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
    myItem.Subject = "Hello world" 
    myItem.Display 

End Sub
```

The [Recipient.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property depending on the type of recipient returns or sets an integer corresponding to the numeric equivalent of one of the following constants:

- `JournalItem` recipient: the `OlJournalRecipientType` constant `olAssociatedContact`.
- `MailItem` recipient: one of the following `OlMailRecipientType` constants: `olBCC`, `olCC`, `olOriginator`, or `olTo`.
- `MeetingItem` recipient: one of the following `OlMeetingRecipientType` constants: `olOptional`, `olOrganizer`, `olRequired`, or `olResource`.
- `TaskItem` recipient: either of the following `OlTaskRecipientType` constants: `olFinalStatus`, or `olUpdate`.

For example, to add a new recipient to the `CC` field:

```
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Eugene Astafiev")  
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```