# Paste E-mail Address from Excel cell to to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send birthday greetings. I have a list of e-mail addresses and dates.

I filter by date. How do I copy the e-mail address and send?

I know how to copy the content but the Outlook doesn't support that configuration for pasting.

```
Sub Envia_Emails()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
         
    Call Filtrar_aniversario
    Worksheets("Query").Activate
    Activated.Cells(2, 2).Copy
    
    With OutlookMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = PasteSpecial
        .Subject = "Feliz Aniversário!"
        .Body = "Feliz aniversário"
        .Display ' para envia o email diretamente defina o código  .Send
    End With
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub


Sub Filtrar_aniversario()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("A:D").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _
        ("M4:M5"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post how your spreadsheet looks like?

Comment: here is example on adding email list https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303646/4539709

Comment: @0m3r

It's a simple spreadsheet with two relevant columns, E-mail addresses and date of birth.
The Date are used to advanced filter on the column D (no problem with that) and there is the column of the e-mail address on the column B.

Comment: Thanks for the example that you replied, but i don't know how to send just one e-mail with all the addresses in the BCC field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to copy an email address to the clipboard and paste it. You can directly set the `To` / `CC` / `BCC` properties to string with either a single email address or a `";"` separated list of email addresses.

```
.BCC = Range("M4:M5").Text
```

**UPDATE** The following scripts worked fine for me:

```
Sub Envia_Emails()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Call Filtrar_aniversario
    With OutlookMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = Application.Range("A1:A1").Text
        .Subject = "Feliz Aniversário!"
        .Body = "Feliz aniversário"
        .Display ' para envia o email diretamente defina o código
        '.Send
    End With
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: off the top of my head:

```
 for each r in Application.Range("B2:B6")
   set recip = OutlookMail.Recipients.Add(r.Text)
   recip.Type = 3 'olBCC
 next
```

Comment: I'm already tried to do that, but doesn't worked. Seems pretty easier, but i'm already a newbie in that language, so how 'll indicate that property as a String to be recognazed by Outlook? And this work as well with Cells references?

Comment: Use the Text property (`Range.Text`)

Comment: I've tried, but doesn't export to Outlook. I have to define another instruction before?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: There it's. The Outlook open the window, but without any E-mail Address.


`Sub Envia_Emails()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
     
    Call Filtrar_aniversario
      
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutlookMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = Range("B2:B6").Text`

Comment: Firstly, get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` - you are hiding errors

Comment: without this part they gave to me the message "Error in time of execution '440'

There is no support in the object for this method"

Is something like that, because my Excel are on portuguese language.

Comment: Does it work if you replace that line with `.BCC = Application.Range("B2:B6").Text`? You are running this in Excel VBA, right?

Comment: Doesn't work. Yes, i'm running in Excel VBA.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "Error in time of execution '440' There is no support in the object for this method"

Comment: It means Application object does not support the `Range` method. What is your complete script?

Comment: `Sub Envia_Emails()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
     
    Call Filtrar_aniversario
      
    With OutlookMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = Application.Range("B2:B6").Text
        .Subject = "Feliz Aniversário!"
        .Body = "Feliz aniversário"
        .Display ' para envia o email diretamente defina o código  .Send
    End With
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub`

Comment: I had no problem running that script from `ThisWorkbook` - I commented out the `Call Filtrar_aniversario` line and changed the range to A1:A1. You also should not call Display *and* Send. It is either/or.

Comment: The thing about "Call Filtrar_Aniversario" it's right. That're to aply advanced filter in the date with another script.
About other things, I'm really trying to follow this steps, without sucess. You can retype my script with your appointments?
I'm really embarassed to waste your time.

Comment: Yes, reg script above (see the updated answer) worked for me.

Comment: Really worked with a single E-mail, but with multiple e-mails obtained with Advanced Filter doesn't work. The position is a variable too, because the intention are to send E-mail with their respective birthday on list, and the list are with 3690 names.

Comment: Then you need to loop through the cells or search results and either call `Recipients.Add` for each address or construct a single string with multiple addresses separated by `";"` and assign that string to the BCC property.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but i don't know how to do that.
Thank you for everything.

Comment: See the updated answer above

Comment: Great! I'm already trying to pick just the visible data in column "B". Getting that, it's done.
Thank you so much, Dmitry.